# Binary search tree: return occurrences of a word from a text file

Tags: java, return-value, binary-search-tree

This is my first post so apologies if I haven't quite got the framing of the question quite right yet. I'll put my hands up straight away and say this is part of my 'homework', I've got about 99% of it done but I've got this niggling bug that has been driving me crazy all week and I simply can't see the wood through the trees here.

The basic concept is that we have a text file, a poem of sorts, that our program has to look at and then place into a binary tree. We should record each word, the occurrence of each word and which line it appears in. I have managed to do that, save for that for in the example `"And I went to StackOverFlow and I asked the question, and the answer was..."` my program *should* return that the word `"And"` appears in line 1 (which it currently does), but it is currently recording every occurrence of that word and it should only record that the word "and" occurs in line 1 and not every instance of it.

So in the above example `"And I went to StackOverFlow and I asked the question, and the answer was.."`

So just picking out the word `"And"` here since it occurs multiple times, my program is currently returning:

`"And [1, 1, 1]"`

But it *should* be returning:

`"And [1]"`

I have supplied the code for the entire program, but the method I think to focus on is the `recordWord` method, at the final `else if`, something isn't quite right there clearly! Apologies if this explanation is hugely convoluted but I couldn't think of another way to explain it! Any help would be hugely appreciated

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 * A class representing a binary tree containing words.
 * 
 */
public class WordTree {

    public String word;
    public ArrayList<Integer> lineNumbers;
    public WordTree left, right;

    /**
     * Constructs a tree consisting of a single node, with the given word and
     * line number.
     * 
     * @param w
     *            the word
     * @param lineNo
     *            the line number
     * @pre true
     * @post word tree containing word w on line lineNo has been constructed
     */
    public WordTree(String w, int lineNo) {
        word = w;
        lineNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        lineNumbers.add(lineNo);
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    /**
     * Records a new occurrence of the given word, in the tree.
     * 
     * @param w
     *            the word
     * @param lineNo
     *            the line number
     * @pre this is a well formed binary search tree
     * @post if word was not in this tree, then the word and its line number
     *       line have been inserted into ordered word tree, else line has been
     *       appended to line-number list for word (if we haven't already
     *       recorded that line number for this word)
     */
    public void recordWord(String word2, int lineNo) {
        if (word.compareToIgnoreCase(word2) < 0) {
            if (right != null) {
                right.recordWord(word2, lineNo);
            } else {
                right = new WordTree(word2, lineNo);
            }
        } else if (word.compareToIgnoreCase(word2) > 0) {
            if (left != null) {
                left.recordWord(word2, lineNo);
            } else {
                left = new WordTree(word2, lineNo);
            }

        } else if (word.compareToIgnoreCase(word2) == 0) {

            lineNumbers.add(lineNo);

        }
    }

    // System.out.println("method recordWord not implemented yet");

    /**
     * Displays all the words in this tree.
     * 
     * @pre this is a well formed binary search tree
     * @post words have been written out in alphabetical order, each followed by
     *       ascending list of line numbers on which the word occurs
     */
    public void display() {

        if (left != null) {
            left.display();
        }
        System.out.println(word + lineNumbers);

        if (right != null) {
            right.display();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Counts how many different words there are in this tree.
     * 
     * @pre this is a well formed binary search tree
     * @return the number of different words in tree
     */
    public int numberOfEntries() {
        int count = 1;
        if (left != null) {
            count += left.numberOfEntries();
        }
        if (right != null) {
            count += right.numberOfEntries();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: From what I can see the `[1,1,1]` output is correct. Why are you assuming it should only output `[1]` when "And" has 3 occurrences in your example, all on line 1? If you only want it to record the first instance then your call to `lineNumbers.add(lineNo)` should have some sort of additional check

Comment: "SHOULD return that the word "And" appears in line 1 [...], but it is currently recording every occurrence of that word" That's why.

Try to check if your word-line pair is already in your tree. That could help.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm working from quite a constrained specification here. The specification has suggested implementing the code so that it records every instance of a word in a line first, as that is easier, and then going back and updating it so it just displays that the X appears in Y sentence but disregards how many times. My code currently counts every instance of a word in the sentence, which according to the specification is not what they want

Comment: How about a `Set<Integer> lineNumbers`? Or even better have the line words as a Set (HashSet, TreeSet=OrderedSet) so one adds the words per line only once.

Comment: Joop your solution sounds quite interesting, but I'm not sure how I'd implement that. I've been coding for a very, very short time and everything is an uphill battle at the moment! Would you be able to point me in the right direction please?

Comment: @TheCapn - the "some sort of additional check" is correct, I just can't for the life of me figure out what that check should be! It's not quite that I want to record the first instance, it's just that assuming there are multiple instances of the same word in one line, the program should 'know' there are multiple instances, I only want the program to output that there is AN occurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since List accepts duplication, it may accepts elements with the same value. Instead, you could use Set interface which eliminates duplication for you automatically. In your example, you can declare *lineNumbers* as a *TreeSet* to print the output in ascending line number.

Declare *lineNumbers* as a Set

```
public Set<Integer> lineNumbers;
```

Then initialize it in the constructor using TreeSet

```
lineNumbers = new TreeSet<Integer>();
```

It's all that you need to change. Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: That solved the problem perfectly, thanks very much! I'm going to go read up on the "Set" interface now, which I hadn't considered before. Thanks again!